# Background in html

Tags: html, web, pycharm, background

Hii guys I'm new to the community

So I am currently trying to make an html website using pycharm I did most of it now but I want to add a background picture or colour.
Does anyone know the code for it ?

I tried

```
<img src='background.jpeg'>
```

And

```
<style> </style>
```

And I saved the picture on my pc but it didn't work

Comment: There is no CSS in your `<style>` tag, so it's not clear exactly what you expected that to do.  For the `<img>` tag, in what way did it fail?  If you haven't started using your browser's debugging tools, now is a great time to do that.  With them you can observe the current state of the page's DOM, any errors on the console, network requests (for things like images) and the server's response to those requests, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like below?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css"> <!-- include the path to the style2.css if it's not in the same folder-->
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Something...</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and in your style2.css

```
body{
    background-image: url('images/somepicture.jpeg'); /*assuming you have saved the picture in the images folder */
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your picture also in the `root-folder`, where your `index.html` lies?
Or you do it with `Internal-Styles`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {background-color: powderblue;
      background-image: url('images/somepicture.png');} /* Path to your picture */
h1   {color: blue;}
p    {color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```